# How should we deal with question 76997?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure how to deal with this question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/76997/which-is-better-staying-with-10-04-lts-until-12-04-comes-out-or-upgrading-to-11

I could categorize it as *not constructive* and close it because the OP doesn't provide any information on what would be *better* for him.

> **not constructive**
>   This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

In other words he seems to be asking for opinions rather than answers based on facts.

The first sentence of the highest voted answer shows what I mean.

> From **My point of View** Avoid Upgrading to 11.10 or 11.04.

Should we close that question as *not constructive*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close as a duplicate of the question below and move on, [as was done with this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45870/which-should-i-recommend-10-04-vs-11-04).

- [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks! :)